# How to generate dynamic expression with a bitwise operator and enums?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, expression, bit-manipulation

Let's say I have the following enum.

```
[Flags] public enum Color { Red = 1, Blue = 2, Green = 4 }
```

Now, I want to use the following query to find Red shirts.

```
Shirts.Where(x => (x.Color & Color.Red) != 0)
```

And it works just fine, but when I try to construct this dynamically:

```
var color= Expression.Constant(Color.Red);
var property = Expression.Property(Expression.Parameter(typeof(Shirt)), "Color");
Expression.NotEqual(Expression.And(property, color), Expression.Constant(0));
```

I get the following exception:

> *The binary operator And is not defined for the types 'MyEnums.Color'
>   and 'MyEnums.Color'.*

I'm using .NET 4.5

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try converting color and property to the underlying type using [`Expression.Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292051.aspx) first:

```
var color= Expression.Constant(Color.Red);
var property = Expression.Property(Expression.Parameter(typeof(Shirt)), "Color");
var colorValue = Expression.Convert(color, Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(Color)));
var propertyValue = Expression.Convert(property, Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(Color)));
Expression.NotEqual(Expression.And(propertyValue, colorValue), Expression.Constant(0));
```

Comment: +1 for complex expression building. You can always see the structure of Expression using LINQPad `Dump` for `Expression<Func<Shirt, Color>> exp = shirt => shirt.Color & Color.Red;`

Comment: @IvanMilutinović Glad it works - it's been a couple years since I needed that method and I wrote it from memory only... :o :)

Comment: how can i do the same thing but i want a complex expression : i.e i want to query shirts that are red or yellow or blue or white